# Email Validation using Regular Expressions Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, email-validation

I would like to do a simple email validation for list import of email addresses into a database. I just want to make sure that there is content before the @ sign, an @ sign, content after the @ sign, and 2+ characters after the '.'  . Here is a sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

errors= {}

data= {'First Name': ['Sally', 'Bob', 'Sue', 'Tom', 'Will'],
     'Last Name': ['William', '', 'Wright', 'Smith','Thomas'],
     'Email Address': ['sally@gmail.co.uk','bobby123@gmail.com','suewright_123@yahoo.gov','tom.smith23@students.wacs.fl.us','']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is the expression I was using to check for valid emails:

```
regex = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+')
def isValid(email):
    if re.fullmatch(regex, email):
      pass
    else:
      return("Invalid email")
```

This regex is working fine but I am not sure how to easily loop through my entire df email address column. I have tried:

```
for col in df['Email Address'].columns:
   for i in df['Email Address'].index:
      if df.loc[i,col] = 'Invalid email'
           errors={'row':i, 'column':col, 'message': 'this is not a valid email address'
```

I am wanting to write the invalid email to a dictionary titled errors. with the above code I get an invalid error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I'd probably do

```py
df["Email Address"].str.match(r"^.+@.+\..{2,}$")
```

`str.match` returns `True` if the regex matches the string.

The regex is

- the start of the string `^`
- content before the @ sign `.+`
- an @ sign `@`
- content after the @ sign `.+`
- a dot `\.`
- and 2+ characters after the '.' `.{2,}`

Comment: thie description is an oversimplification. This will match something like `@@@.@@` which is not a valid emai address

Comment: @onyambu yes, you're absolutely right. The crux is `str.match` though, and I think OP would be better off using some ready-made solution for a common task like e-mail recognition, anyway. (If it is crucial to the task, that is, and the question didn't sound like a precise matcher is needed).

Answer (score 1):

The beautiful thing about Pandas dataframes is that you almost never have to loop through them--and avoiding loops will increase your speed significantly.

`df['Email Address'].str.contains(regex)` will return a boolean Series of whether each observation in the Email Address column.

Check out [this chapter](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.10-working-with-strings.html) on vectorized string operations for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through rows using .iterrows() on a dataframe. row contains a series and you can access your column the same way you would a dictionary.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if not isValid(row['Email Address']):
        print("Invalid email")
```

Comment: The function defined in the question.